# How to create section breaks representing the theme

Tags: attention

Since my earlier question [What are the symbols that pass time called](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/55987/what-are-the-symbols-that-passes-time-called), I would like to ask if anyone could instruct me how to make the section breaks symbols instead of the basic (...) and (***).
Graphic is one method but I don't really want to make a hassle out of it, so I'm looking for a better way to create stylish section breaks in my story to represent the theme.

Comment: What software are you using to write in?

Comment: I'm writing on Docs for now and debating whether or not to put it on Word (I'm not technically a Word expert since I have a 50/50 chance of my document getting save.)